# what is the use of <absolute-ordering> tage in web.xml in spring mvc

Tags: java, servlet-3.0

```
  <absolute-ordering/>
```

what is the use of the `absolute-ordering` tag in `web.xml` in a Java web application.

Answer (score 0):

The  element specifies which web fragment JARs (according to the names in their WEB-INF/web-fragment.xml files) have to be scanned for SCIs, fragments and annotations. An empty  element configures that none are to be scanned.
[https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/HowTo+FasterStartUp#:~:text=The%20element,none%20are%20to%20be%20scanned.](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/TOMCAT/HowTo+FasterStartUp#:%7E:text=The%20element,none%20are%20to%20be%20scanned.)

But I personally think it is better to remove spring-web-X.X.X-sources.jar if you are planning to fix your issues with absolute-ordering tag
[Tomcat Server Won't Start When Following Spring MVC Guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69486856/tomcat-server-wont-start-when-following-spring-mvc-guide/69487628#69487628)

Comment: Suggesting to remove `spring-web` when someone is using Spring MVC is a very bad idea as this will break the application.

Comment: In the link that I provided it says to remove the "spring-web-5.1.5.RELEASE-sources.jar" not the jar itself.